# Python: Is it possible to change the Windows command line shell current directory without changing the actual current directory?

Tags: python, cmd, working-directory

I'm using `os.system()` to do Windows command line shell executions. I would like to change the Windows cmd current directory. Here's one way of doing it:

```
os.chdir('newPath')
```

But `chdir()` will also change the actual Python current working directory. I don't want to change the actual Python working directory because I want other parts of my script to run in the original current working directory. What I want to change is only the Windows cmd current working directory. In other words: I want `os.system()` commands to run in one current working directory (Windows cmd current working directory) while anything else should run in another current working directory (the actual Python current working directory).

Here's another try to change **only** the Windows cmd current directory:

```
os.system('cd newPath')
```

However, that obviously doesn't work since right after the execution of the `cd newPath` command the Windows cmd current directory is reset (because I won't use the same Windows command shell in the next call to `os.system()`).

Is it possible to have a separate current working directory for the Windows cmd shell? (separate from the actual current working directory).

Comment: `I would like to keep the current working directory while only change the Windows cmd current working directory` - what?

Comment: @BlueRaja: You're right. I wasn't clear. Just edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `subprocess` module is intended to replace `os.system`.

Among other things, it gives you `subprocess.Popen()`, which takes a `cwd` argument to specify the working directory for the spawned process (for exactly your situation).

See:  http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Example usage replacing `os.system`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("yourcmd" + " yourarg", shell=True, cwd="c:/your/path")
sts = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please add a few words on the `os.waitpid()` thing?

Comment: @snak waitpid is described in the doc. You could even guess what it does.

Comment: `retcode = subprocess.call(["yourcmd","arg1","arg2"], shell=True, cwd="c:/your/path")`

Answer (score 1):

If it only has to work on Windows, one way might be:

```
os.system('start /d newPath cmd')
```

Comment: why not just 'start cd mypath'? hoevever it's not quite clear where this question is going, considered what zigdon and others pointed out

Comment: I guess the same kind of solution is applicable to Linux as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `os.system`, you're not reusing the same command shell, but spawning a new one for each request. This means that you can't actually expect changes in it to propagate between invocations.

You could write a wrapper though, that will always change to the directory you want before launching the command.

Comment: Thanks, but I know the fact that I'm not reusing the same shell. What I was asking is how to overcome that problem and change the windows current dir without changing the actual current dir.